# TS: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature when defined dynamically, but it works

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm still quite new to typescript, so please be gentle with me if I'm doing something with no sense for this technology!

The problem that I'm trying to solve is having a dynamic way to define how my application errors should be structured, but leaving to the users the faculty to enrich the messages.

So I tried to create this logic in a module that could be extended easily from the application, but I'm currently facing the problem:

```
Error:(35, 18) TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'ErrorMessage' has no compatible call signatures.
```

What I thought it was a good idea (but please tell me if I'm wrong), was to use a register and a map to have the possibility to extend this mapping every time I want. So I created my `ErrorMessage` interface to be like the following:

```js
export interface ErrorMessage {
  actionMessage: string;
  actionSubject: string;
  originalErrorMessage?: string;

  toString: () => string;
}
```

and a register for these, called `ErrorResponseRegister`, as it follows:

```js
export enum defaultErrors {
  ExceptionA = 'ExceptionA',
  ExceptionB = 'ExceptionB',
}

export class ErrorResponseRegister {
  private mapping: Map<string, ErrorMessage>;

  constructor() {
    this.mapping = new Map()
      .set(defaultErrors.ExceptionA, exceptionAErrorMessage)
      .set(defaultErrors.ExceptionB, exceptionBErrorMessage);
  }
}
```

So at the end, every `ErrorMessage` function should look like:

```js
export function exceptionAErrorMessage(originalErrorMessage?: string): ErrorMessage {
  return {
    enrichment1: "Something happened",
    enrichment2: "in the application core",
    originalErrorMessage: originalErrorMessage,

    toString(): string {
      return `${this.enrichment1} ${this.enrichment2}. Original error message: ${originalErrorMessage}`;
    },
  };
}
```

*Please note I haven't used classes for this ones, as it doesn't really need to be instantiated*

and I can have a bunch of them where the `toString()` method can vary. I just want to enforce the errors should have an `enrichment1` and `enrichment2` that highlight the problem in a better way for not-technical people.

So, now, back to code. When I'm trying to use the `exceptionAErrorMessage` statically, I can't see any problem:

```
console.log(exceptionAErrorMessage(originalErrorMessage).toString())
```

But when I try dynamically, using the map defined in the `ErrorResponseRegister`, something weird happens:

```js
// In ErrorResponseRegister
public buildFor(errorType: string, originalErrorMessage?: string): Error {
  const errorMessageBuilder = this.mapping.get(errorType);

  if (errorMessageBuilder) {
    return errorMessageBuilder(originalErrorMessage).toString();
  }

  return "undefined - do something else";
}
```

**The code works as expected**, the error returned is in the right format, so the `toString` function is executed correctly.

BUT, the following error appears in the IDE:

```
Error:(32, 18) TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'ErrorMessage' has no compatible call signatures.
```

The line that causes the problem is

```
errorMessageBuilder(originalPosErrorMessage).toString()
```

Can someone help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I also noticed that when I remove one of the properties in the exported function `exceptionAErrorMessage`, the IDE spots that the return type is not assignable, but if I remove the `toString()` function, nothing happens

Comment: Please try to edit this code into a [mcve] where the only issue present is the one you're facing.  Ideally you'd be able to drop the code as-is into an IDE with no dependencies, like [The Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).

Comment: "if I remove the `toString()` function, nothing happens"... this is a different issue, right?  All objects in JavaScript already have a [`toString()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString); if you don't override it you'll get one from the prototype.  If you want type checking here, you should use a different method name that isn't guaranteed to exist on all objects.

Comment: It is at this point, I thought that the problem was in the interface and that was a symptom of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is you've mistyped `mapping`... it doesn't hold `ErrorMessage` values; it holds `(x?: string)=>ErrorMessage` values:

```
private mapping: Map<string, (x?: string) => ErrorMessage>;
```

---

What's unfortunate is that you initialize this variable via `new Map().set(...)` instead of the using an [iterable constructor argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Parameters).

The former returns a `Map<any, any>` which is trivially assignable to `mapping` despite the mistyping.  That is, you ran smack into [this known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29786#issuecomment-463075463) where the [standard library's typings for the no-argument `Map` constructor signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.1/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L32) produces `Map<any, any>` which suppresses all kinds of otherwise useful error messages.  Perhaps that will be fixed one day, but for now I'd suggest instead that you use the iterable constructor argument, whose [type signature declaration](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.1/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L33) will infer reasonable types for the keys/values:

```
constructor() {
  this.mapping = new Map([
    [defaultErrors.ExceptionA, exceptionAErrorMessage],
    [defaultErrors.ExceptionB, exceptionBErrorMessage]
  ]); // inferred as Map<defaultErrors, (orig?: string)=>ErrorMessage>
}
```

If you had done so, it would have flagged the assignment as an error with your original typing for `mapping` (e.g., `Type 'Map<defaultErrors, (originalErrorMessage?: string | undefined) => ErrorMessage>' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, ErrorMessage>'.`)  Oh well!

---

Once you make those changes, things should behave more reasonably for you.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgUSimgFlgBnczAczwG8AoOOHGBCJMym4ALjnIwoyagG4mLbGw4BlAK4AjAFbAp-QcKRiJ0BNWSYANoWJQuVWgH51QkeIkwIM21v4AKAJRwAvAD4BLtoAvgwMoJCwcMBIcgC2cAAmwFhyhjAm0ORwjMz4ILhg0kgAgj5wAER5BUXF5QA0ElXAhexIAEJllfnNRW3lDCFh4NDw2IaYlARE0ABKFJBI5MBz+oJo2RJgwgBumKhwsZhgYCL8JEcAPBoidXBuINYBmtReflOm5jy+9szYHBpyKTQTwbZjMGAACwQ5AAdIdjiIykhgAB3ODnMBuADaEjBcCxSRSaQyUFhTRaHGKt1A1VaxRJn1oAF0GnjmATkphUulpqSYeTetTuhT2gyKBZgEzcXAmR5xMxBswwIpDAhsHAFHIEIYEgAxYFoUwAFQAnmA+E8bnBdPokEYxdwrDZnh5nYicmC-ot4IbSOKeG0tTr1t44JDoXCjictDDaDA3L6oKbzXLQniEOg7onGcBA9qklAvB68VBgDA5FAkFFeTm88GoG4bQZjDX-bQPDDHM5np55WDFWDS+XKxU5EhCchgAk4ABaRIQAQQWJlqFaKKGJblPshQZJMaYUtwdBjqStKLCmoOiVuHTCW321uO4CPa5aBiu95+p-2PfjQ-HpBTw4c9aQ4Norx4G9mCbO0Ww+NtnzdN8Pwg2hxCAA)

Comment: That works perfectly. I used `.set` in the map because in the example I saw online was always done that way. I didn't know about the known issue... I was thinking the problem was in the interface definition (that's why I posted that comment about `if I remove the toString() function, nothing happens`)